# Error Handler while the file is missing in the given path

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a vba code to open multiple files and copy the content of that files and paste it in the master file. when a file is missing in the specified location compiler is throwing error and I can able to handle that and continue with the next file. However, if the error occurs for the second time program is getting stopped.

Code

```
On Error GoTo ErrH:

ErrH:
MsgBox strFileName & "is missing."
Sheets(strListSheet).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

GoTo Continue
```

Comment: You need to use `Resume Continue` rather than Goto (if your routine is structured properly) but it's a lot simpler to use something like: `If Dir(your_path) <> vbNullString Then` to test if the file exists.

Comment: The file could exist and still not be able to be opened. The error handling when trying to open a file is still required.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common ways on handling errors like this

- Seperate Error handler

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    On Error GoTo ErrH
    For ' loop your File Names


        Set wb = Nothing
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
        If Not wb Is Nothing Then
            ' Do your stuff

        End If
    Next 'strFileName
Exit Sub
ErrH:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        ' File not found error
        Resume Next
    Else
        ' Handle other Errors
        MsgBox Err.Description
    End If
End Sub
```

- Inline error handler

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    On Error GoTo ErrH
    For ' loop your File Names


        Set wb = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
        On Error GoTo ErrH
        ' if wb is nothing then strFileName wasn't found
        If Not wb Is Nothing Then
            ' Do your stuff

        End If
    Next 'strFileName
Exit Sub
ErrH:
    ' Handle other Errors
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree with the first one but can't seem to follow the second although I've never tested it. Btw, I posted an answer but if it is somehow the same as your second(just a typo thing) then I'll delete it.

Comment: @l42 my inline example _is_ the same as yours in all key respects!

Comment: Ah I get it. But I can't say it is totally the same so I'll leave it here for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this version of inline error handling:

```
For Each strfilename In strfilenames '~~> just for example
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
    On Error Goto 0 '~~> required to capture any other error which might occur.

    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Do something
    End If
    wb.Close False '~~> close file without saving
    Set wb = Nothing '~~> set wb variable to nothing 
Next
```